# PHP foreach with exif_read_data keep saying Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach, image-manipulation, exif

i tried several variant of getting exif info written out. but in every case i had similar problem:

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" --
>   in: foreach ($section as $name => $val)

```
$exif = @exif_read_data($result['path'], 'IFD0');

 if(is_array($exif))
  foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
   foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
     echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Do you know which foreach is giving error. Try remoing @ from the front of exif_read_data maybe ?

Comment: the second foreach is giving the problem, with @ removed its still the same (originally i had it without @..)

Comment: Add if is_array($section) before the 2nd foreach and see if that works ? It is possible that some or all of the $section values are not array so you can't use foreach loop to traverse through the array.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works! `if is_array($section) `

Comment: You might also want to add an else case for this if to display the values when $section is an array.

Answer (score 1):

place if (is_array($section))

before the second foreach statement..
It is possible that some or all of the $section values are not array so you can't use foreach loop to traverse through the array.

big thanks to   Maximus2012